# How to cast UInt to SInt value in Chisel3?

Tags: chisel

As tile, how to cast UInt to SInt value in Chisel3 in right way?
ig:

```
val opC    = RegInit(0.U(64.W))
val result = RegInit(0.U(64.W))
result := Mux(opC.toSInt > 0.S, opC, 0.U)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on if you want to reinterpret as an SInt (same width), or actually cast (ie. casting an 8-bit UInt results in a 9-bit SInt).

You should **reinterpret** a UInt to an SInt by calling `.asSInt` on the UInt. eg. `opC.asSInt`, the result will be the same width.

You should **cast** a UInt to an SInt by calling `.zext` on the UInt. eg. `opC.zext`, the result will be 1-bit wider with a zero in the msb.