# How to connect Bits to SInt in Chisel

Tags: scala, riscv, chisel

I am adding an accelerator to the Rocket-chip core, and getting Type mismatch error when trying to connect  SInt wire from my code to the ROCC interface which is Bits.

"Type mismatch. Cannot connect myRocc.io.dx to cmd.io.deq.bits.rs1."

Is there any option to cast this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see answer in [How to cast UInt to SInt value in Chisel3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49081218/how-to-cast-uint-to-sint-value-in-chisel3)

I should note that Bits is really just an alias for UInt

Comment: Thanks! it seems toUInt and to toSiInt were deprecated